# Validar campo unico en formulario modal ajax codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, modal

tengo un formulario en modal para ingresar datos, y me valida que los campos estan vacios antes de guardar, pero ¿como hago para validar que uno de los campos sea unico? que no se pueda repetir la información.
Esta hecho con codeigniter usando modal, el codigo es este.
Los input son asi

```
             <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">First Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

...

```
function save()
{
$('#btnSave').text('saving...'); //change button text
$('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable 
var url;

if(save_method == 'add') {
    url = "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_add')?>";
} else {
    url = "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_update')?>";
}

// ajax adding data to database
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {

        if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
        {
            $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
            reload_table();
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
            {
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
            }
        }
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error adding / update data');
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

    }
 });
}
```

y en el controlador

```
  public function ajax_add()
  {
    $this->_validate();
    $data = array(
            'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName'),
            'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastName'),
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
            'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
        );
    $insert = $this->person->save($data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
  }
```

la que valida los campos vacios

```
  private function _validate()
{

    $data = array();
    $data['error_string'] = array();
    $data['inputerror'] = array();
    $data['status'] = TRUE;

    if($this->input->post('firstName') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'firstName';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'First name is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($this->input->post('lastName') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'lastName';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Last name is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($this->input->post('dob') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'dob';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Date of Birth is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($this->input->post('gender') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'gender';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Please select gender';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($this->input->post('address') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'address';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Addess is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($data['status'] === FALSE)
    {
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();
    }
}
```

esta es la parte del modelo que guarda, elimina y actualiza

```
    public function get_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}

public function save($data)
{
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

public function update($where, $data)
{
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}

public function delete_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete($this->table);
}
```

get_by_id optiene el id para editar la información.

Comment: Estás queriendo validar si uno de los campos es único comparandolo con la DB?

Comment: si por ejemplo el campo firstname sea unico comprobandolo con la bd, ya coloco el modelo en la pregunta inicial.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías validarlo en el mismo input al perder el foco (blur). Y al momento de guardar en tu función "save" comprobarlo.

```
$(document).on('blur','firstName', function(){
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      // url con ruta a tu método o función en el controlador
      url: verify_firtsName,
      data: { 'firstName' : $(this).val() },
      success: function(msg){
        if (msg==1) { // duplicado
          $(this).addClass('invalido');
          alert("Tu Mensaje al usuario"); 
        } else{ // firtsName unico 
          $(this).removeClass('invalido');
        }   
      }
  });
});
```

El código de la clase css (podria ser cualquier otro que gustes):

```
.invalido {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

La función o método en el controlador codeigniter podría ser así:

```
public function verify_firtsName() { 
    $valor = $this->input->post('firsName');
    $resultado = $this->tu_modelo->find_firtsName($valor);
    if($resultado) {
       echo 1;
    } else { 
       echo 0;
    }
}
```

La función en el modelo:

```
function find_firstName($valor) {
    $this->db->where('firtsName',$valor);
    return $this->db->get('tabladb')->result();
}
```

Dentro de la función Save  debes validar el input simplemente comprobando si el input tiene la clase "invalido" definida. O bien cualquier otro atributo que quieras indicarle, incluso podrías crear un input hidden para controlar esto pero ya sería mas fastidioso.

Para validarlo según este ejemplo bastaría con este código:

```
var obj = $("input[name=firtsName]");
if(obj.hasClass('invalido')) {
   alert('el nombre ya existe');
   return false;
}
```

Si detectas la clase asociada pues detienes la función.

Espero haberte ayudado o darte una idea de como puedes resolver. Saludos!

Comment: Hola, gracias, voy a intentar implementarlo para ver que tal. Saludos